# AngularJS with list

Tags: list, angularjs, cordova

I'm doing an employees list that is loaded from SQLite database. I don't know why my list is empty, but I can see via JSON.stringify that data is comming.
I'm using AngularJS and Cordova Framework. Debugging with Ripple.

listEmployees.html

```
   <div data-role="page" apply-jq-mobile>    
            <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
                <h3>
                    Header
                </h3>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">
                <div class="ui-grid-a">
                    <div class="ui-block-a">
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui-block-b">
                        <a data-role="button" href="#/new" data-icon="plus" data-iconpos="left">
                            New
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <input type="text" ng-model="search" class="search-query" placeholder="Search">
                <ul data-role="listview" data-divider-theme="b" data-inset="true">
                    <li data-role="list-divider" role="heading">
                        Employees
                    </li>
                    <li data-theme="c" ng-repeat="employee in employees">
                        <a href="#/edit/{{employee._id}}" data-transition="slide">{{employee.name}}</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

EmployeeCtrl

```
    function EmployeeCtrl($scope, Employee){

        $scope.employees = Employee.getAllEmployees();

        $scope.saveEmployee = function(id) {
            if(id){
                //TODO
            } else {
                Employee.addEmployee($scope.employee);
            }

        }
    }
```

Employee

```
app.factory('Employee', function() {
    var data = {};
    data.addEmployee = function(_employee, callback) {
        var employee = new Employee();
        employee = _employee;
        DbService.db.employees.add(employee);
        DbService.db.saveChanges(callback);
    }

    data.getAllEmployees = function() {
        DbService.db.employees.toArray(function(employees) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(employees));
            return employees;
        });
    };

    return data;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I solved it.

```
function EmployeeCtrl($scope, Employee){

    Employee.getAllEmployees(function(employees){
        $scope.employees = employees;
        $scope.$apply();
    });
}
```

.

```
app.factory('Employee', function() {
    var data = {};
    data.getAllEmployees = function(callback) {
        DbService.db.employees.toArray(function(employees) {
            callback(employees);
        });
    };

    return data;
});
```

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use promises. Your call to db is asynchronous and therefore view is getting rendered before your data arrives.

```
data.getAllEmployees = function() {
    var $d = $q.defer();
    DbService.db.employees.toArray(function(employees) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(employees));
        $d.resolve(employees);
    });
    return $d.promise;
};
```

Angular templating system wait for all the promises to get resolved before rendering. So I think this will solve your problem.

Comment: You need to inject $q as dependency in service. If its outputting it to console then it should work

Comment: I inserted here: app.factory('Employee', function($q) There is another location that I should inject?